# Printing contents of Bootgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-bootgrid

I have googled around and am not able to find a solution to this problem, or if there is one.

Has anyone experienced in Jquery Bootgrid, been able to print the contents of grid?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "printing the contents of grid"? You want to call a `console.log()` in javascript with a json representing the grid data? Or do you mean printing in a paper (with a printer)? Or do you mean just printing the rows in the browser with html?